# AngularJS 1.5 scope in directive ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

Here's some code http://jsfiddle.net/miuosh/n6yppypj/ with uploadfile directive. The problem is that I use this

```
  <input type="file" file-model="myFile" />
  <button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
```

in ng-include="'views/uploadFileForm.html'".

In directive I add "myFile" to scope. It turns out that Angular create new scope with myFile. To add "myFile" to "rootScope" I need to use

```
modelSetter(scope.$parent.$parent.$parent[..],element[0].files[0])
```

which is inconvenient because I need to know how many parent scope I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced similar problem dealing with file input with angular. 
you can create a directive which will listen to file change and call its controller function with file. Here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acsckrhL/1/) for it.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('yourCtrl', function() {
    $scope.image;
    $scope.imageChanged= function (files) {
        $scope.image = files;
    };
});

app.directive('customOnChange', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var onChangeFunc = scope.$eval(attrs.customOnChange);
      element.bind('change', function(event){
        var files = event.target.files;
        onChangeFunc(files);
      });

      element.bind('click', function(){
        element.val('');
      });
    }
  };
})

<input type="file" id="imgInput" custom-on-change="imageChanged"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helps.